# Sequelize belongsTo and include

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am having a hard time making use of BelongsTo relationship in a query.

Here is the relationship:

```
models.Area.hasMany(models.Airport);
models.Airport.belongsTo(models.Area, {foreignKey: 'areaId', as: 'area'});
```

Now I try to run a query:

```
models.Airport
    .findAll( {
        where: { active: 1 },
        include: { model: models.Area }
        })
```

I get an error:

```
   Error: area is not associated to airport!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out.  I can't say I fully understand the problem, but here it is.

When creating the relationship, I use as: 'area'.

The result is, I need to add as: 'area' to the include statement:

```
models.Airport
.findAll( {
    where: { active: 1 },
    include: { model: models.Area, as: 'area' }
    })
```

Once the two match, things go better.